# How to fix "Could not load theme preview: Error parsing XML," when trying to upload my own written code on blog

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogs

I am a front end developer. I wrote an HTML template and tried to upload that HTML template on my blog. but when I was trying to save them a message pop up

```
(Error parsing XML, line 170, column 3: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".)
```

I only have two link tag in the whole file which is used for google font. When I erased the link tags and try to save again then another message pops up:

```
(Could not load theme preview: Error parsing XML, line 168, column 3: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".)
```

I don't understand how to solve this. if anyone has any idea please advice what to do.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 4, 51, 0.86), rgb(0, 165, 195));
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.body img {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.offer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.offer p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 58px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 17px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.offer a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #010059;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transition: .4s;
}

.offer a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #010059;
}


/*=========== Responsive =============*/

@media (max-width:575px) {
  .body img {
    width: 172px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 38px;
  }
  .offer p {
    top: 45px;
    font-size: 51px;
  }
  .offer a {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    top: 271px;
    right: 52px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:576px) and (max-width:767px) {
  .body img {
    width: 160px;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
  .offer p {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .offer a {
    top: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  .body img {
    width: 176px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
  .offer p {
    font-size: 47px;
  }
  .offer a {
    top: 200px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}


/*
            
            @media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
                .body img{
                    width: 180px;
                    margin-top: 17px;
                    margin-left: 53px;
                }
                .offer p {
                    font-size: 65px;
                    
                }
                .offer a {
                    top: 235px;
                    padding: 15px 15px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                }
            }
    */

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .body img {
    width: 180px;
    margin-top: 17px;
  }
  .offer p {
    font-size: 80px;
    top: 100px;
  }
  .offer a {
    top: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Win Samsung Galaxy S10</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="body">
    <img src="final-samsung-phone.png" alt="final-samsung-phone">
  </div>
  <div class="offer">
    <p>Win Samsung Galaxy S10</p>
    <a href="#">Claim Your Offer</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your parser, you may need to "self" close your `meta` and `link` tags like this (note the `/`):

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" />
```